# Remove unwanted parts of string by regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string which looks like this:

```
position=&region_id=&radius=&companytype=&employment=&scope=&salary_from=&salary_to=&pe
```

Is it possibe to preg_replace all unwanted parts of string above except "radius=" and "scope=" ?

P.S. All query params in the string may follow in random way.

Comment: You could parse your query string into an array and then just delete the elements with the keys `radius` and `scope`

Comment: See parse_str() and http_build_query().

Comment: Yea, i know that i can use explode, then foreach with condition "if not", but 
it seems that this is not so elegant as preg_replace :)

Comment: Your question seems awkward to me. Why not simply delete all query strings and set `radius` and  `scope` ? i.e.: `$queryString = "radius=&scope="`

Comment: @Pedro Lobito No, because it's a simplified example. This string is dynamic. Some params may simply be absent. I.e. i can't set them statically.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution to your need :

```
<?php

$str = "position=&region_id=&radius=&companytype=&employment=&scope=&salary_from=&salary_to=&pe";

// parse the string
parse_str($str,$output);

// unset the unwanted keys
unset($output['position']);
unset($output['region_id']);
unset($output['companytype']);
unset($output['employment']);
unset($output['salary_from']);
unset($output['salary_to']);
unset($output['pe']);

// transform the result to a query string again
$strClean = http_build_query($output);

echo $strClean;

?>
```

Comment: He said, expect 'radius' and 'scope'

Comment: My bad ! Thanks for the correction, I've edited my answer

Comment: What about if the params have data assigned to it? for example "&radius=blablablabla", your implode will strip it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed that too, now It's working properly :)

Comment: Nice. The only problem I see with this is what if another parameter was added e.g "&new=mydata" and so on. He would need to unset it again and again and so on ..

Comment: Maybe a regexp could do this indeed

Comment: Vincent, Andre thanks guys :) this is not a universal way. My example is very simplified. In the real life the string might be ambiguous with various params :)

Answer (score 0):

If you define an array using the parameters you want to keep as keys, you can use `array_intersect_key` after `parse_str` to get only those parameters without needing to explicitly remove all the unwanted ones.

```
$wanted_keys = array('radius' => 0, 'scope' => 0);  // the values are irrelevant
parse_str($str, $parsed);
$filtered = array_intersect_key($parsed, $wanted_keys);
$result = http_build_query($filtered);
```

If you want to define an array with the wanted keys as values, you can use `array_flip` to convert them to keys.

```
function filterQuery($query, $wanted_keys) {
    $wanted_keys = array_flip($wanted_keys);
    parse_str($query, $parsed);
    return http_build_query(array_intersect_key($parsed, $wanted_keys));
}

$result = filterQuery($str, array('radius', 'scope'));
```

Comment: There are many approaches to solving this simple problem. Thanks for another one :) But I wanted to know about the solution by using regexps.